# Updating MaterialUI's "TextField" value causes other TextField values on the page to clear

Tags: reactjs, textfield

I'm trying to update the label of a TextField when ever a change is detected in its input.

Here's my state initially:

```
state = {
    loginDetails: {
        email: "email@gmail.com",
        password: "password"
    },
    isLoading: false,
    error: null
};
```

Here's what my MatUI TextField elements look like:

```
<TextField
    type="text"
    name="email"
    label="email"
    value={this.state.loginDetails.email || ""}
    variant="outlined"
    onChange={this.change}
/>
<TextField
    type="password"
    name="password"
    label="password"
    value={this.state.loginDetails.password || ""}
    variant="outlined"
    onChange={this.change}
/>
```

Whenever a change is detected within the TextField itself, this function fires:

```
change = event => {
    this.setState({
        loginDetails: { [event.target.name]: event.target.value }
    });
};
```

I believe this line: `loginDetails: { [event.target.name]: event.target.value }` is the problem.

If my state looked like the following, with the following change function, everything works as expected and there is no clearing/resetting:

```
state = {
    email: "email@gmail.com",
    password: "password"
    isLoading: false,
    error: null
};

...

change = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
};
```

But, I want the email and password to be in its own object, for a multitude of reasons.

[Here's what the page looks like on initial load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nX6v.png)

[Here's what happens after clicking into the password field and typing a character (the email field clears)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpBXQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code

```js
change = event => {
    this.setState({
        loginDetails: { [event.target.name]: event.target.value }
    });
};
```

You replaced `loginDetails` with an object with a single field (event.target.name)

Try merging the object instead of replacing it.

For example

```js
change = event => {
    const newLoginDetails = Object.assign(
        {},  
        this.state.loginDetails,
        { [event.target.name]: event.target.value }
    )
    this.setState({
        loginDetails: newLoginDetails
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why it works in this case? 

change = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
};

Curious why it changes when you want to update an object within the state.

Comment: this.setState function always merges the state object for you, but it does not deeply merge so you have to merge nested object by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, issue is here

```
this.setState({
    loginDetails: { [event.target.name]: event.target.value }
});
```

this will either keep `username` or `password`, coz you are assigning only one field `loginDetails: { [event.target.name]: event.target.value }`,

So Change it to :

```
this.setState((state) => {
    loginDetails: {
        ...state.loginDetails, // <--- get username and password
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value // <--- over write the field
    }
});
```